# Cannot add into database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Id,Reciever_Area,Parcel_Type,Delivery_Type,Parcel_Weight,Final_Cost")] quotation quotation)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.quotations.Add(quotation);    <-- this isn't working
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View(quotation);
}
```

This is the error message I get:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The entity type quotation is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: It sounds like your instance of `DbContext` is not aware of the `Quotation` type.  I would need to know information about how you are generating your `DbContext` (database first, code first) class before providing additional detail.

Answer (score 1):

Since the quotation object is not created in the current dbContext thus you've to attach it before adding it.

```
 db.quotations.Attach(quotation);
 db.quotations.Add(quotation);
```

Comment: The line of code `db.quotations.Add(quotation);` attaches the entity (in this case, `quotation`) to the `DbContext` and sets its state to `Added`.  That said, the first line of code is not needed.